# Copying a range of cells from one workbook to another with openpyxl - AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am fairly new to python and wanted to see if I could automate some basic stuff. I am having trouble with the following bit of code.
I would like to copy cells `A1:B20` from one workbook and paste it into another one. I get it work with a single cell, but as soon as I try to define a cell range, I get the error

> AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'value'

A pointer into the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


wb_raw_data = load_workbook(filename = 'D:\Folder\Test.xlsx')

sheet1 = wb_raw_data.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

wb_to_change_data = load_workbook(filename = 'D:\Folder\Existing.xlsx')

sheet2 = wb_to_change_data.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet4')

cellrange = sheet1['A1':'B20'].value

sheet2['A1':'B20'] = cellrange

wb_to_change_data.save('D:\Folder\Existing.xlsx')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do. You need to loop through the rows in the range and then through the cells in each row.

Comment: @CharlieClark Thank you very much. I was able to solve my problem using loops and therefore can save several minutes at work every day!